# CoreMidi : logging received midi messages to an NSTextField

Tags: xcode, cocoa, coremidi

Sorry, I don't speak English (I'm using Google Translate).

I'm very new to Xcode. I'm trying to write an app that can listen to received midi messages and show them in an `NSTextField` (just like a midi monitor).

I use `CoreMidi` and I am able to connect the app to the desired input and receive Midi messages (I can print them using `NSLog`). How I can output these message (the same ones I can read in `NSLog`) in an `NSTextField`?

I set a property, `@synthesize`d it and connected the NSTextField in Interface Builder, but from the midi callback function I can't access it (it says "Undeclared").

Here the code in MyDocument.h

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSTextField *test_messages;
```

Here the code in MyDocument.m

```
@synthesize test_messages;

void midiInputCallback (const MIDIPacketList *list, void *procRef, void *srcRef) {   
id POOL = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
UInt16 nBytes;
NSString *ric;
const MIDIPacket *packet = &list->packet[0];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < list->numPackets; i++) {
    nBytes = packet->length;
    UInt16 iByte, size;

    iByte = 0;
    while (iByte < nBytes) {
        size = 0;
        unsigned char status = packet->data[iByte];
        if (status < 0xC0) {
            size = 3;
        } else if (status < 0xE0) {
            size = 2;
        } else if (status < 0xF0) {
            size = 3;
        } else if (status < 0xF3) {
            size = 3;
        } else if (status == 0xF3) {
            size = 2;
        } else {
            size = 1;
        }

        switch (status & 0xF0) {
            case 0x80:
                ric = @"Note Off";
                break;

            case 0x90:
                ric = @"Note On";
                break;

            case 0xA0:
                ric = @"Aftertouch";
                break;

            case 0xB0:
                ric = @"Control change";
                break;

            case 0xC0:
                ric = @"Program Change";
                break;

            case 0xD0:
                ric = @"Channel Pressure";
                break;

            case 0xE0:
                ric = @"Pitch Wheel";
                break;

            default:
                ric = @"Unk";
                break;
        }
        //TEST HERE
        [test_messages setStringValue:@"TEST TEST"]; //THIS GET "test_messages undeclared (first use in this function)"
        iByte += size;
    }
    packet = MIDIPacketNext(packet);
}
[POOL release];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
MIDIClientRef midiClient;
MIDIEndpointRef src; 

OSStatus result;


result = MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("MIDI client"), NULL, NULL, &midiClient);
if (result != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Errore : %s - %s",
          GetMacOSStatusErrorString(result), 
          GetMacOSStatusCommentString(result));
    return 0;
}

result = MIDIDestinationCreate(midiClient, CFSTR("Porta virtuale"), midiInputCallback, NULL, &src);
if (result != noErr ) {
    NSLog(@"Errore : %s - %s",
          GetMacOSStatusErrorString(result), 
          GetMacOSStatusCommentString(result));
    return 0;   
}

MIDIPortRef inputPort;
result = MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, CFSTR("Input"), midiInputCallback, NULL, &inputPort);

ItemCount numOfDevices = MIDIGetNumberOfDevices();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfDevices; i++) {
    MIDIDeviceRef midiDevice = MIDIGetDevice(i);
    NSDictionary *midiProperties;

    MIDIObjectGetProperties(midiDevice, (CFPropertyListRef *)&midiProperties, YES);
    MIDIEndpointRef src = MIDIGetSource(i);
    MIDIPortConnectSource(inputPort, src, NULL);
}

return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **) argv);
}
```

Thank you in advance for any information that can help me.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to register the callback and the callback function itself?

Comment: Thank you very much for reading me :)
Code added (hope in a right way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem that you're having is that you're assuming that the MIDI callback function "knows" about your `MyDocument` class and is able to access its properties. Unfortunately, that's not the case. C functions have no inherent state information, the only way to pass information to a function is to pass it as an argument.

That's what all the `void* refCon` arguments are in the documentation. `refCon` is a generic pointer that you can use to pass a reference to some other object to your function.

For instance, the docs show the signature for the `MIDIInputPortCreate()` function as follows:

```
extern OSStatus MIDIInputPortCreate(
    MIDIClientRef client, 
    CFStringRef portName, 
    MIDIReadProc readProc, 
    void *refCon, 
    MIDIPortRef *outPort );
```

In your particular case, you should be passing a reference to your `MyDocument` object as the `refCon` parameter. At present you are passing `NULL`.

```
MIDIPortRef inputPort;
result = MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, 
    CFSTR("Input"), 
    midiInputCallback, 
    myDocument,  //note the change
    &inputPort);
```

Then, in your callback, you can access the document object and therefore its properties:

```
void midiInputCallback (const MIDIPacketList *list, void *procRef, void *srcRef) 
{
    //do some MIDI stuff here

    //get a reference to your document by casting the void* pointer
    MyDocument* myDocument = (MyDocument*)procRef;
    //log the message to the text field
    [myDocument.test_messages setStringValue:@"TEST TEST"];
}
```

That should be how it works. However, in your code above you seem to have a `main()` function *inside* your `MyDocument.m` file. That is ***completely and totally incorrect***. If you are using a Cocoa document-based app, you should not be altering the `main()` function at all except in very rare circumstances.

Instead, you should do all of your MIDI setup in the `‑windowControllerDidLoadNib:` method of `NSDocument`, which is called when the document's window is loaded and the outlets are guaranteed to be ready.

Something like this:

```
@implementation MyDocument
@synthesize test_messages;

void midiInputCallback (const MIDIPacketList *list, void *procRef, void *srcRef) 
{
    //do some MIDI stuff here

    //get a reference to your document by casting the void* pointer
    MyDocument* myDocument = (MyDocument*)procRef;
    //log the message to the text field
    [myDocument.test_messages setStringValue:@"TEST TEST"];
}    

‑ (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController*)windowController
{
    //set up midi input
    MIDIClientRef midiClient;
    MIDIEndpointRef src; 

    OSStatus result;

    result = MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("MIDI client"), NULL, NULL, &midiClient);
    if (result != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Errore : %s - %s",
              GetMacOSStatusErrorString(result), 
              GetMacOSStatusCommentString(result));
        return 0;
    }

    //note the use of "self" to send the reference to this document object
    result = MIDIDestinationCreate(midiClient, CFSTR("Porta virtuale"), midiInputCallback, self, &src);
    if (result != noErr ) {
        NSLog(@"Errore : %s - %s",
              GetMacOSStatusErrorString(result), 
              GetMacOSStatusCommentString(result));
        return 0;   
    }

    MIDIPortRef inputPort;
    //and again here
    result = MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, CFSTR("Input"), midiInputCallback, self, &inputPort);

    ItemCount numOfDevices = MIDIGetNumberOfDevices();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfDevices; i++) {
        MIDIDeviceRef midiDevice = MIDIGetDevice(i);
        NSDictionary *midiProperties;

        MIDIObjectGetProperties(midiDevice, (CFPropertyListRef *)&midiProperties, YES);
        MIDIEndpointRef src = MIDIGetSource(i);
        MIDIPortConnectSource(inputPort, src, NULL);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: It's perfect!!
Thank you sooooo much :D

Comment: Is it working? MIDIGetNumberOfDevices returns number of all devices (source and destination), but MIDIGetSource should work in range of 0..MIDIGetNumberOfSources-1.

And why do youcall MIDIObjectGetProperties anyway?